# Drive Genius 3 Demo does not have a menu. How do I uninstall it on my iMac?

Tags: imac

I have the Drive Genius 3 demo and it does not have a menu or an Uninstall. How do I delete the demo version of Drive Genius 3?

Comment: Please edit in some details if your question isn't the same as the linked one. If somehow reinstalling the app and then having it clean itself isn't an option - just edit that in and we can re-open this. As written, it's not going to get a different answer than the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "AppCleaner" it is free and will delete all associated files with an application.

Comment: I would only resort to an app cleaner if a quick search of the vendor site didn't have uninstall instructions, and if a question here came up with no further exact steps... The reason is that app cleaners generally do a poorer job than the maker or someone that knows how the app actually works.